# Loop through an array with button click

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to loop through the months with the click of a button.

When a user clicks add a new row then January Feb, march, and April are all appear. I want that it stops after April, where a new row cannot be added.

```
<a class="btn btn-primary rounded-0 btn-block" id="insertRow" href="#">Add new row</a>
       <script>
                                                    
         $(function () {

           // Start counting from the third row
           var months = ["January", "February", "March", "April"];
                                                        
           $("#insertRow").on("click", function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var newRow = $("<tr>");
           var cols = '';
           // Table columns
           cols += '<th scrope="row">' + months + '</th>';
           cols += '<td><input class="form-control rounded-0" type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="First name"></td>';
         // Insert the columns inside a row
           newRow.append(cols);
          // Insert the row inside a table
         $("table").append(newRow);
          // Increase counter after each row insertion
           months++;
           });
           // Remove row when delete btn is clicked
           $("table").on("click", "#deleteRow", function (event) {
           $(this).closest("tr").remove();
            counter -= 1
            });
            });
            </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no `table` in you code. So you need to create a table DOM. Also `months++` is not making sense in your code as `months` is an array. Hence comment that

```js
$(function() {

  // Start counting from the third row
  var months = ["January", "February", "March", "April"];

  $("#insertRow").on("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var newRow = $("<tr>");
    var cols = '';

    // Table columns
    cols += '<th scrope="row">' + months + '</th>';
    cols += '<td><input class="form-control rounded-0" type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="First name"></td>';


    // Insert the columns inside a row
    newRow.append(cols);

    // Insert the row inside a table
    $("#table").append(newRow);

    // Increase counter after each row insertion
    //months++;
  });

  // Remove row when delete btn is clicked
  $("table").on("click", "#deleteRow", function(event) {
    $(this).closest("tr").remove();
    //counter -= 1
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="btn btn-primary rounded-0 btn-block" id="insertRow" href="#">Add new row</a>
<table id="table"></table>
```

Comment: Ok thanks, so how do I make it, so it shows individual months when I click add new row?